# HTTP request using the same session but to different URLs

Tags: http, post, vbscript, http-post

Lets say I  have developed a VBScript function (which I haven't), which does an HTTP POST to a specific URL and awaits back the response. Now that response I need to resubmit it back to another (different) URL but with the same session ID. Is there a way to do this?

Just to post a way I thought this might work.

```
Function HTTPPOST(URL1,URL2,Message)
  Set ohttp = createobject("msxml3.serverxmlhttp")
  ohttp.Open "POST", URL1,False
  ohttp.send message
  response= ohttp.responseText
  ''Now I want to resend the response back to a different URL2
End Function
```

Comment: Have you tried a new `.open` and `.send` calls with the same object instance?

Comment: URLs on the same Server, I assume... as a Session can't be shared between different servers.

Comment: i haven't cause I thought that open establishes the connection and thus the session. so either I was thinking doing open but asynchronous and then when receiving the first answer to resend to another not sure...